# Saving Entire Activity State

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, savestate

I have an Android app, that allows the user to dynamically add their own buttons to the layout. I need to make it so that once the app is closed and re-opened, this dynamically added button returns to the layout. Instead of loading the default layout.

Currently, I'm dynamically adding buttons through the ActionBar of the App:

```
    if (id == R.id.add_button) 
        {
        String string = "Adding Button in Progress";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );

        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Button");

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
        layout.addView(myButton);

        //myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;    
        }
```

This creates the Button fine, however when the app is closed and re-opened, it launches up the default layout.

I've done some research on having the app save and reload the updated layout. It seems that I need to use onSaveInstanceState. Here is what I have so far in terms of trying to save the layout:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the app state here:
    savedInstanceState.putAll(savedInstanceState);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

And here is what I have in terms of trying to "reload/restore" said layout. Notice I'm not using onRestoreInstanceState, instead I'm doing it through the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        //savedInstanceState.get(savedInstanceState);
        } 

    else 
        {
        //initialize members with default values for a new instance
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm saving/loading correctly, but any advice on how I can accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

P.S. I'm still a fairly new member so I couldn't comment/ask questions on existing threads.

I know there's a lot of information out there on trying to load/save layouts, however in my case I need it to save the Button, and not a string of user text. In other words, its not a fixed value that I need to save. If the user adds n buttons, when the app is exited and relaunched, it should have those same 3 buttons.

Comment: Combination of ViewStub & SharedPreferences will solve your problem.

Comment: @VVB: 
 
thanks for the reply. I tried looking into SharedPreferences before but was turned away due to the fact that I'm not sure how to represent the state of an activity (namely the recently added buttons) as a key-value pair that SharedPreferences seems to require.

Answer (score 0):

Saved Instance State is a key-value pair about your activity. The documentation clearly says that it is destroyed when the app is closed .(pressing back button or if the system itself shutsdown the app).This is only useful when you are navigating within the app or changing orientation.

One solution is to create a Shared Preference of the details your application needs to identify the given structure consisting the dynamic contents. The fetch the values whenever you open the app and code according to it.

Other solutions are to use databases or files to store data about your dynamic content.

Comment: One thing that I couldn't seem to understand about the Shared Preference approach, is how to represent a newly added Button as a key-value pair.

Comment: As in there's methods that you can use such as putBoolean and putInt which stores values using key-val pairs. But as far I know there's no way to represent a Button as a String, Boolean, Integer etc?

Comment: dont store the entire button as shared preference.save its attributes or properties and then  render the button using the given data.

Answer (score 0):

just store the String or Boolean.. when ever you try to use them in onRestoreInstanceState then create Button or anything dynamically and use stored String or boolean to set text on them